# How to add an entity API accessible serial field?

Tags: 7, entities

I have tried [Serial](https://drupal.org/project/serial), it works almost what I want, excepts I can't access my field via `entity_metadata_wrapper('node',$myNode)`. Serial field can't be find in `dpm($wrapper->getPropertyInfo())`, I guess the reason is it lacks entity API support.

Can it be accessed via entity API? Is there any other similar module exists?

Thank you!